# The operator > is undefined for the argument type(s) java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

```
public void sort(){
    //TO DO
    int k = start;
    int temp = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<size-1; i++){
          for(int j=0; j<size-1; j++){
                if((cir[(k % cir.length)]) > cir[((k+1) % cir.length)]){
                      temp = cir[(k % cir.length)];
                      cir[k%cir.length] = cir[(k+1)%cir.length];
                      cir[(k+1)%cir.length] = temp;
                }
                k = (k+1)%cir.length;
          }
    }
}
```

//Here the cir[] type is object. but why this problem is occurring?

Comment: The operator `>` makes no sense for the Object type

Comment: The title of your question answers the question. The operator `<` (as well as `<=`, `>` and `>=`) is (are) not defined for `Object` (or really any reference-type, Java does not allow operator overloading). You may want to read [Oracle's tutorial on Object Ordering](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html).

Comment: The cir array probaly contains objects. You can't compare objects with >.

Comment: So sir now what should i do?

Comment: What does the cir array contain?

Comment: Post a [mcve]...

Comment: it contains integers Sir

Comment: Is `Integer` the actual type of `cir[]`?

Comment: no sir. cir[] type is Object

Comment: How is this a surprise then? Object > Object does not work in Java. Change the array to `int[]` or `Integer[]`.

Comment: ok Sir. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The operators <,> are not defined for `Object`.
How would you compare them? 
Define a method for the class of the object you are using. Say `greaterThan(YourObjectType otherobject)`. Then implement it according to how you want to compare. That depends on `YourObjectType`.

**Edit**. 
Implement the Comparable interface as added in a comment.

Comment: "*Say `greaterThan(YourObjectType otherobject)`.*" - No. Use the [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html)- or [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)-interface. And please use [camelCase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case) for your variable names.

Answer (score 0):

The others have already mentioned it but I will reiterate: if you want to write some generic sort method you'd want to either provide a `Comparator` or have the elements implement `Comparable`.

With generics your methods could look like this:

```
public <T extends Comparable<T>> void sort(T[] array) { ... }
public <T> void sort(T[] array, Comparator<T> comparator) { ... }
```

Both variants require the user to provide some code that defines how `<`, `==` and `>` are defined for the objects in question (the methods `Comparable.compareTo(right)` or `Comparator.compare(left, right)` return a negative (normally -1) int, 0 or a positive int (normally 1) to indicate `<`, `==` or `>`).

In general, you'd use `Comparable` if you can define a *natural* (default) ordering, e.g. if you'd work with an array of people they normally might be ordered by name.

`Comparator` on the other hand is more flexible and normally used if you can't or don't want to use a default order. In that case you'd provide a comparator for each case, e.g. when you'd want to sort cars either by price or speed you'd provide a comparator that internally either compares prices or speed.

Note that this doesn't work for primitives like `int` etc. Thus you'd either have to convert them to their wrapper classes, e.g. `Integer` or provide custom methods that make use of the "normal" operators.